# $-1$ in the reals vs the compex numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers, real-numbers

If we take $-1$ as a number in the reals it has no square root, it is undefined, however, if we take $-1$ in the complex numbers, it has a square root, namely $i$, how do we understand this seemingly different properties of the same number depending on the set? How can we consider the 'number' as being a single object in this case, Is it a property of number's to be defined differently in different 'universes'?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138916/discussion-on-question-by-user37577-1-in-the-reals-vs-the-compex-numbers).

Answer (score 6):

> If numbers, being immutable must keep their properties?

This is simply not true. $2$ considered as an element of $\mathbb{N}$ has the property that $ab=2$ implies $a=2$ or $b=2$. If we consider $2$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}$, this is false. The properties of objects are dependent on the context.

Comment: Or, $0$ is the smallest number in $\mathbb N$ but obviously not in $\mathbb Z$. Good answer, and I hope the OP can think of plenty of similar "properties" themselves.

Comment: Is the immutable fact because in a given context $N$,$R$, etc it's properties do not change? I don't see how it can exactly be the same object if it's properties change? There are many examples of this, all I can assume is that technically speaking it's not the same object.