# How do we understand a 'universe' in the context of Mathematics?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, foundations, philosophy

I recently open a can of worms for myself by inquiring if there is a difference between a number as a natural or real, and got a fair answer, in doing so I came by an interesting idea about viewing the numbers slightly differently in different sets, such as '[why does -1 have no square root if left in the natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520934/1-in-the-reals-vs-the-compex-numbers)?' My issue with this question is that I do not really understand the idea of a universe.

Let's take a simple example, let's take an element $x$ in a set $A$ and an element of a subset $B$, What I fail to understand is, do we define the universe simply as something we 'discuss', or do we simply pretend that all elements of $A$ that aren't in $B$ simply do not exist? Doing so makes it like we create two different realities, one where they exist, one where they do not, and how can $x$ be the same object in this case?

How can an object exist in different 'universes' if we define them in a way that they sort of exist independently with their own sense of what exists and what does not? Is this too much of me trying to view them as real objects in real 'universes'? And how can we define properties of an object to define it, for example as given before $-1$ has a square root in one universe and doesn't have it in another, is this part of our 'universe' definition, I.E. a relation an object can have with a particular universe.

I understand that in the strictest sense they aren't the same objects, but more interestingly how it works, say I split $N$ into a smaller subset.

Comment: I would not know where to start answering this question. On one hand, you are introducing a concept of "universe" so it falls to you to define it. On the other hand, as set theory is underpinning the modern mathematics, one could think of the "set of everything" - but this notion is self-contradictory. (Then you would have the "set of all sets", and as a subset "the set of all sets that don't contain themselves" - Russel's paradox.) How this is resolved in a modern set theory on one hand, and why it doesn't really worry many people outside of set theory is a matter for a whole book!

Comment: To emphasize, $\Bbb R$ is not a subset of $\Bbb C$ in the strictest sense.  There is a subset of $\Bbb C$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$, making it equal in almost every way it matters... *except* for how it is rigorously defined.  Further, operations like $\times$ in $\Bbb R$ are not technically the exact same operation as their counterparts in other contexts like $\times$ in $\Bbb C$.  Yes, they are used in much the same way and have many of the same properties, however they are not strictly speaking "*the same thing.*"

Comment: There *is* a "*universe of discourse*"... which is how you refer to the current context in which you are working.  Yes, certain properties of certain objects depend on which context you are working in.  Plain and simple.  As for the specific example of $-1$ and square roots... having a square root is not an intrinsic property of $-1$ on its own... it depends also on which specific $\sqrt{~}$ and what context we are referring to.

Comment: Also, to define a *property* of an element, you want to study mathematical logic, in particular *predicate logic*. That would compel you to distinguish the *syntax* of the property (e.g. $P(a):\equiv(\exists x) x^2=a$: $P$ is true for variable $a$ if there exists $x$ such that $x^2=a$) from *semantics* of the property. (On a *set* $X$ with a defined relation $=$ (equality) and operation $\times$ (multiplication), for every element $a\in X$ you can evaluate whether there *is* $x\in X$ such that $x^2=a$.) We don't call $X$ an universe but a *model*. This is a long story in itself.

Comment: The existence of the universe certainly does not depend on how we define it.

Comment: @JMoravitz so it's better to say $-1$ has no square root in this universe of discourse, instead of thinking in the universe it doesn't exist at all (but allowing for existence outside it).

Comment: It's that we have decided to not talk or use the object i.e. if our universe doesn't include the natural number 2 it doesn't mean that 3 is the successor to 1,

Comment: Mathematics is a social discipline in that we examine ideas together to reach conclusions under skeptical conditions. If we have nothing to agree on there is nothing for us to do so we conjure universes with as few offending assumptions as possible then examine the consequences of our creation. Sometimes this resembles reality either by design or by coincidence but we are not so constrained, you merely have to convince someone it's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just making it more complicated than it has to be. Any set can be considered a universe as long as the math you're working with is confined to that set. When working with a set, we almost always regard it as a subset of some larger set.

For instance, let's consider the set of prime numbers $P = \left\{2,3,5,7,11,\ldots\right\}$. If we're asked to name elements that aren't in $P$, then we'd probably say 4, 6, 500, or any composite number. Obviously, a number like $-0.43$ isn't in that set, but that wouldn't come to our minds because it's completely irrelevant of what is a prime number and what is not. So we have an unstated assumption that $P \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ because $\mathbb{N}$ is the "most natural setting" in which to talk about primes. We can say in this situation that $\mathbb{N}$ is the universe.

Comment: I guess so, I think the word 'universe' makes you think it's bigger than it is, I.E. we imply it doesn't exist, I think the word from logic 'domain of discourse' is an easier way of talking about the similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the same as $n \in \mathbb{R}$ just look at how these two sets are defined.

The short and useful answer is: Yes, they are equal.

The long and mostly useless (unless you are doing set theory) answer is: no, since $\mathbb{N}$ is built like $\bigl\{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}  \},... \bigr\}$ (Von Neumann definition) and $\mathbb{R}$ is defined via the Dedekind cuts and its elements are different from that of $\mathbb{N}$.
However, you can find something identical to $\mathbb{N}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$, so usually you work like if $\mathbb{N}$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$, leaving this formalisms to set theorists.

Usually, when you talk about natural and real number, you don't talk about the formal sets definitions, so you can assume that you are talking about natural numbers inside real numbers.

Regarding the concept of 'universe', we need a definition. Intuitively, the univers is composed by the elements you are working with, so if you look at $B$ as a subset of $A$, $A$ could be the universe. A formal definition could be taken using the classes. A universe for a property (proposition) $\varphi(x)$ could be defined as a class of the elements on which you want to 'test' the property.

For instance, if your property is $\varphi(x)=$ "$x \in B$", you can consider as class $A$, which, in this case, is also a set.

An example where you use a proper class (a class which is not a set) could be $\varphi(x)=$ "the cardinality of $x$ is finite" and you want to consider as universe the groups.

When you are talking about the square root of $-1$, you want to define it. The definition could be $\forall \ x\in A \ \sqrt{x}=\{y \in A : y^2=x\}$, so, it depends on $A$. If you take $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $x=-1$ you have that this set is empty, while if you take $A=\mathbb{C}$ you will have $\sqrt{x}=\{i, -i\}$. It's all about definitions.

I hope I have given the answer you were looking for, the question was a bit vague.

Comment: I understand how they can be different objects, but could I make my 'universe' a subset of the naturals and have the same objects in different universes?

Comment: If you take $A=\{n \in \mathbb{N} : n > 5\}$ and $B=\{n \in \mathbb{N} : n < 10\}$ you have that $6,7,8,9 \in A$ and $6,7,8,9 \in B$ are the same objects (sets)

Comment: In which case, how do deal with the same object in differing universes, they are universes of 'discourse'? I.E. When I talk about something like the square root of a real number $-1$ I'd say its outside the universe (of what I can talk about) not that it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: The point is that you have to define what you do: it's wrong to say just "the square root of -1 does not exist". You have to specify where you are working (if you want you can call it universe but you are not giving a formal definition so it's not worth talking about universes). 
The only thing you can say is: "the square root of x exists/does not exist in the set A". Clearly if $x=-1$ and $A=\mathbb{R}$ then does not exist, if $A=\mathbb{C}$ it exists. It depends on what you need, if you have to work only with real numbers  then $\sqrt{-1}$ does not exist

Comment: Makes sense, I just found it strange that in different universes, somethings can exist and some others can't, yet the same objects can exist in different universes. but when we see it from a less material way, (more what we can talk about, not whether the objects just somehow disappear from existence) it makes more sense.

Comment: If you want to see it in a more "real world" way, think about it like that: does a person 2,30 mt tall exist? In your house or maybe also in your city, no. In the world, yes. He (the tall person) has not disappeared, you were just looking in different places (and also, in this case, the two places are one a subset of the other, because your house or your city are a part of the world)